# Object of type 'closure' is not subsettable error when trying to run simulation

Tags: r, simulation

I am trying to run a simulation of a probability matrix with 5 states.

```
N<-10 #for 10 simulations
state<-simulat(P,N,1) #P is a matrix defined earlier in my code

for(i in 1:N)
    {
        if (state[i]=='0')
        {
            time[i]<-rexp(1,Mu)
        }
        if (state[i]=='1' || state[i]=='2' || state[i]=='3')
        {
            time[i]<-rexp(1,(Mu+Lamda))
        }
        if (state[i]=='4')
        {
            time[i]<-rexp(1,Lamda)
        }
    }
Error in time[i] <- rexp(1, Mu) : 
  object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
```

Is this an issue with formatting or am I defining my state[i] incorrectly? I have tried switching my [] to (), but then it gives me an error that says it could not find function 'state', even though I had just defined it above. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: There's a function called `time()`. Unless you've initialized a vector called time (e.g. `time <- rep(NA,N)`) R will try to subset the function. Anytime you see "object of type 'closure'" in an error, R just means "a function". (And probably best not to name the vector time, anyway, just to avoid confusion.)

Comment: @joran is right, but even if you change `time` to, say, `tiempo`, you will have an error (a different one, though). The conclusion is that you need to create a vector `time` beforehand : `time <- numeric(N)`. Or, better `tiempo <- numeric(N)`, and use `tiempo[i]` instead of `time[i]`.

Comment: Thank you, once I switched time() to tiempo() and added tiempo as a vector it worked. I didn't realize that since I was writing the code in the script editor in R instead of in notepad++ where it colors words already stored as a function.

Comment: There are enough functions in so many packages that this happens to everyone eventually, syntax highlighting or not. The key (for me) was knowing what "object of type 'closure'" means.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to my comment, here is another solution:

```
tiempo <- ifelse(state == '0', rexp(N,Mu), 
                 ifelse(state == '4', rexp(N,Lambda), rexp(N, Mu+Lambda)))
```

Avoiding the loop is likely to shorten the execution time.